# How to move Tablix row to the next page?

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, row, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

Is it possible to set up `Tablix` somehow or via code so the entire row will be moved to the next page instead of placing between two?
MS Word can do it easily...

[image]

Reading of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239384.aspx is not helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a group and call it 'NumberOfRows' Then you can use the `=Floor((RowNumber(Nothing) - 1)/NumberOfRowsYouWant)` on that groups expression.

Here are some links:
http://jeffprom.com/2012/05/11/ssrs-page-break-after-x-number-of-rows/
http://hussain-msbi.blogspot.com/2012/07/page-break-at-nth-row-in-ssrs-report.html