# How to move the last unfinished record to the next page in the Visual Studio SSRS Report Tablix?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report, with a tablix with 4 rows, so each record will get 4 rows in the report, and I don't know how many record I will have and in certain case the last record get cut by the ssrs report and it other part will be on the next page. I want to move the entire record in the next page.

I try to search something on stackoverflow but I find a solution(it doesn't work for me) but this solution didn't please me because it give a DEFINITE number of rows that I can show in ONE page, but I want to do it dynamically, the record I use are very different so one record can take the half of a page or can take just 2 or 3 line of text, it's very variable. So I don't want a fix number of rows I want to move the record in the next page directly when it incomplete.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798808/how-to-move-tablix-row-to-the-next-page) is the solution I found on stackoverflow

And here is some illustration of my problem:

[image] [image]

Here is  the report design:

[image]

Comment: share your report design including any groupings you may have. Without seeing the design it's hard to see the problem but I would guess you just need to add a parent group and set the 'keep together' property to true

Comment: Keep together did a great job but the first page is blank :/

Comment: I found the solution: you need to change the attribute "keep together". I change put `True` on Details and `False` for the group and for the tablix and it work perfectly ! And I use the group function `= Ceiling(RowCount(Nothing)/6))`